# При расчете необходимого количества лет функция выводит на 1 год больше Python (цикл while)

Tags: python

Написал функцию, которая должна рассчитывать количество лет выплаты по кредиту исходя из максимального лимита на заемщика, суммы кредита и процентной ставки.

Функция при проверке выводит на один год больше, чем необходимо. Понимаю, что нужно как-то округлять значение, чтобы не захватывать один год, или при расчете не учитывать первый год, но не могу понять, как это реализовать в функции.

```
def get_years(amount: int, percent: int, limit: int) -> int:
    year = 0
    limit_new = amount
    while limit_new < limit:
        limit_new += math.floor((percent/100) * limit_new)
        year += 1
    return year
```

- ```
  get_years(1600, 10, 2000)    # необходимое значение года 2
  ```
- ```
  get_years(500, 3, 550)       # необходимое значение года 3
  ```
- ```
  get_years(20000, 10, 21000)  # необходимое значение года 0
  ```
- ```
  get_years(5000, 5, 6500)     #  необходимое значение года 5
  ```
- ```
  get_years(1000, 10, 1100)    # необходимое значение года 1
  ```

Comment: `get_years(1000, 10, 1100)` а тут точно не 0?

Comment: Попробуйте 1) поменять условие цикла на `True` 2) В цикле после limit_new добавить условие `if limit_new >= limit: break`. Тогда, не будет лишнего увеличения `year`

Comment: Не подходит, не прохожу проверку get_years(1000, 10, 1100), должно быть 1, выводит 0

Answer (score 1):

У вас почти все хорошо, только 2 ошибки:

1. Вместо

   ```
   while limit_new < limit:
   ```

   примените

   ```
   while limit_new <= limit:
   ```
2. Вместо

   ```
   return year
   ```

   примените

   ```
   return year-1
   ```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Когда `limit_new == limit`, тоже все в порядке.
2. Команда

   ```
   year += 1
   ```

   в конце цикла готовит проверку для *следующего* года, а цикл закончается тем, что условие не выполняется. И так нужно обратно убрать один год.

---

*Проверка исправленного кода прямо вашими данными:*

```
>>> get_years(1600, 10, 2000) # необходимое значение года 2
2

>>> get_years(500, 3, 550) # необходимое значение года 3
3

>>> get_years(20000, 10, 21000) # необходимое значение года 0
0

>>> get_years(5000, 5, 6500) # необходимое значение года 5
5

>>> get_years(1000, 10, 1100) # необходимое значение года 1
1
```

Comment: Не подходит, не прохожу проверку get_years(1000, 10, 1100), должно быть 1, выводит 0

Comment: Добавил исправление еще одной ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Причина отклонений результата была в том, что не учитывались проценты на проценты, т.е. каждый следующий год проценты должны считаться от суммы с процентами за прошлые периоды. Формула такая: `(1+проценты)**n`, где n - кол-во лет.
Суть расчета в подборе той степени (кол-ва лет), при которой величина `кредит*(1+проценты)**n` не превысит лимит.

Вариант решения через логарифм (быстрый):

```
import math
def get_years2(amount: int, percent: int, limit: int) -> int:
    return int(math.log(limit / amount, (1 + percent / 100)))
```

Вариант решения без логарифма:

```
def get_years(amount: int, percent: int, limit: int) -> int:
    n = 0
    while True:
        if amount * (1 + percent / 100) ** n > limit:
            return n - 1
        n += 1


print(get_years(1600, 10, 2000))  # необходимое значение года 2
print(get_years(500, 3, 550))  # необходимое значение года 3
print(get_years(20000, 10, 21000))  # необходимое значение года 0
print(get_years(5000, 5, 6500))  # необходимое значение года 5
print(get_years(1000, 10, 1100))  # необходимое значение года 1
```

```
2
3
0
5
1
```

Comment: (get_years(5000, 5, 6500))  нет результат все таки должен быть 5

Comment: @Константин можете пояснить, почему 5? по шагам

Comment: Не могу, там стоит автопроверка кода, которая при проверке выдает 5. Задачку эту вижу что решали, значит как то выходили на 5

Comment: @Константин можете привести исходный текст задания? без него непонятна суть расчета

Comment: Николай хочет купить автомобиль, но у него не хватает денег . Поэтому он обратился в банк который выдает кредиты под 10% годовых, и разрешает возвращать тело и проценты одним платежом в концу срока.

Если взять 1600 Дол. США на 3 года, то в конце необходимо заплатить 2129,6  Дол. США. Но у Николая только 2000 Дол. США. Пересчитав заново банк предложил взять кредит на 2 года, тогда он заплатит всего 1936 Дол. США.

Comment: 1600 + 10% = 1760 (160$ проценты за 1 год)
      1760 + 10% = 1936 (176$ проценты за 2 год)
      
Создайте функцию которая по размеру кредита, годовым процентам и ограничением клиента будет вычислять максимальный срок кредита (целое количество лет)

Comment: @Константин теперь все понятно. Скорректировал решение

Comment: Спасибо огромное